# The meaning of indirect effect

Tags: interpretation, mediation

I'm a little bit confused with the interpretation/meaning of indirect effect.

What I observe in my study is:

- association between exposure (E) and health outcome (H1) - by logistic regression, with OR=1.5 and p-val<0.01
- association between exposure (E) and health outcome (H2) - by logistic regression, with OR=1.03 and p-val=0.06
- it is well known that H1 affects H2 (also the association is observed in my data)
- mediation: E - H1 - H2, gives me such results (assuming that all assumption for mediation hold): no direct effect (OR=1.005, 95%CI: 0.997-1.01), and very small indirect effect (OR=1.0008, 95%CI: 1.0005-1.001)

And here are my questions:

1. does it make sense at all to conduct mediation, when the risk for H2 if E occurred is very small (OR=1.03) with p-val=0.06?
2. observing no direct effect of E on H2, mean no causal direct effect of E on H2?
3. such small indirect effect, how that can be interpreted? Might that suggest some effect of E through H1? Can it be interpreted as H1 does not affect H2 (or affect very little) if H1 was due to E (in other words: the effect of H1 on H2 depends on what was the cause of H1)? And this is what intrigues me the most: based on the mediation can we claim about the effect of mediator on the outcome (as mediator might be caused by different factors)?

Example, which I found here http://www.da.ugent.be/cvs/pages/en/Presentations/Presentation%20Tyler%20VanderWeele.pdf, describes the association between given genetic variant and lung cancer, and if the effect of the gene variant is mediated through the number of smoked cigarets per day. They obtained direct effect of the gene variant on lung cancer and no indirect effect through the number of cigarettes/day, the same concluding that effect of gene variant is through other pathways. 
So according to my 3rd question: it would suggest that we do not claim about the effect of mediator on the outcome, since increasing number of cigarettes raises the risk of lung cancer whatever the reason for increased number of smoked cigarettes is.

Comment: Computing direct and indirect effects in non-linear models, like logistic regression, is surprisingly complicated. You cannot easily compute it the way you have done. Instead you can look at http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.0502433102 or http://dx.doi.org/10.1177/0081175012444861  or http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1467-985X.2009.00620.x .

Comment: The problem that the mediator could be caused by multiple factors only arises if such factors may also independently affect the outcome. In this case, you'd have to control for them (as in a regression analysis). Also, such factors must not be affected by your exposure variables, otherwise you have to complicate your model (such variables would be mediators between the exposure and your mediator of interest). See here: ([pdf](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/pdf/10.1146/annurev-publhealth-032315-021402)) for details.